# Girl becomes a tree and then ends up with losing her arms/branches

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a tele-film/short-film/episode on the Indian TV channel Doordarshan (DD1) in late 90s (Most probably coloured).

**Genres:** Sci-fi drama.

**Story:** Happy go lucky girl loves trees and has a habit to go on a swing and sit there for hours thinking about the benefits of trees and she is more into nature than her friends and family. Somehow she lost that swing or the tree got cut or something happened and she got sad.

She used to think about being a tree and helping everyone in a sunny day and giving fruits etc. but after this incident her wish comes true somehow. And one day she becomes the tree on the same location where she used to have her swing and she was happy about it. Kids playing around, travelers sitting below on a sunny day.

Nobody knows that she is the tree but viewers can see her face. One day somebody decides to cut the tree, first they cut the two big branches which were equivalent to her hands and then they cut the tree trunk and carry her in a carriage and somehow during this process somebody realized what happened and they all got sad and we can see her face in tree trunk with pain.

**Broadcast year:** Late 90s or early 2000s.

It was more of a message-full story about trees and their importance and how they feel pain too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Could it be [Cheluvi](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0231348/) (1992)?

> Cheluvi, a poor young woman, has a secret magical power. With the magic, she turns into a tree which produces exotic flowers. Soon, her secret is spotted by Kumar, the son of the village head.

There is a review for the movie on IMDB from the user [zudasiscariat](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0231348/reviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt) who mentions:

> Year released 1992, This particular movie premiered on DD Channel and it was during the Children's Film Festival.

Googling DD Channel has results for Doordarshan, so I assume they are the same.

It looks like it's an adaptation of a story called [A Flowering Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Flowering_Tree:_A_Woman%27s_Tale) by A. K. Ramanujan

From the plot summary:

> She turned into a beautiful tree by performing a strange ritual with her older sister.
>
> She forced her to transform into a tree and broke her branches while plucking the flowers.